# How to save a file from URL to Google Drive

Tags: google-drive-api

is there a way to automatically download a file "example.com/example.zip" directly to my Google Drive instead of downloading it to my server and uploading it again?

Comment: Do you mean without coding? If so I don't think so. With code you can use the Google Drive API.

Comment: Using the API would be preferred. But how? Do I still have to down and upload it, or is there an API call for that?

Comment: no there isn't a way to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Drive API there is no method to upload a file directly from a URL, with [files.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) you still have to upload the media. But if you don't want to use your server, you can go for Apps Script, which gives you access to the Drive API via the [Advanced Drive Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive), as well as the [Built-in Drive service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive), plus some other services like [Url Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) with which you could make a request to download from the URL of the file and capture the blob; then use [`DriveApp.createFile(blob)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#createfileblob) to upload to Drive.

---

The beauty of it, it all happens in the cloud in Apps Script servers. Of course you are subject to Apps Script's and Drive API's quotas and limits.

- [Quotas for Google Services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)